# How to get a ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, deprecated

I just want to get a reference in my Fragment (extends Fragment) to my ViewModel.class (extends from AndroidViewModel). This is how it is described everywhere:

```
UserModel userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(UserModel.class);
```

[description on Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel)

..., but ViewModelProviders is deprecated since long ago.

*This class was deprecated in API level 1.1.0. *

I can't import the class with: 
android.arch.lifecycle.[ViewModelProviders]

it just offers ViewModelProvider and other stuff.

---

How am I able to get an instance of my UserModel.class?

Comment: where did you find *This class was deprecated in API level 1.1.0. *?

Comment: @MaxAves https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but ViewModelProviders is deprecated since long ago

`ViewModelProviders` is not deprecated. So, use `ViewModelProviders`:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(yourFragment).get(UserModel.class)
```

There are *pieces* of `ViewModelProviders` that are deprecated, such as its constructor, but the class overall is not.

**UPDATE: 2020-05-28** *Now* `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated. In Kotlin, use `by viewModels()` and related property delegates. In Java, use `new ViewModelProvider(...).get(UserModel.class)` (for various values of `...` depending on the scope of those viewmodels).

Comment: It is pointed out red. Should I extend my Fragment from another class?

Comment: or should I add a dependency?

Comment: @fabi: "It is pointed out red" -- you are missing the `import` statement. You will also need the `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` dependency, as is noted in [the `ViewModelProviders` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders).

Comment: ViewModelProviders is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Using Kotlin with the latest Android architecture components you should use the `by viewModels()` Kotlin property delegate like so:

```kotlin
class YourFragment : Fragment() {
   private val viewModel by viewModels<YourViewModel>()
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to write a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java)

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new MutableLiveData<List<User>>();
        loadUsers();
    }
    return users;
}

private void loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
}
}
```

And then to use it in your actctivity do something like this

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
    // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

    MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
        // update UI
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated!
Use `ViewModelProvider` understood.

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I solved my similiar problem by adding the following method to my Activities:

```
protected final <T extends ViewModel> T obtainViewModel(@NonNull AppCompatActivity activity, @NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory factory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity.getApplication());
    return new ViewModelProvider(activity, factory).get(modelClass);
}
```

And then I did this in my Fragments:

```
protected final <T extends ViewModel> T obtainFragmentViewModel(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragment, @NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory factory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(fragment.getApplication());
    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment, factory).get(modelClass);
}
```

I already had some abstract super classes for menu purposes so I hid the methods away there so I don't have to repeat it in every activity. That's why they are protected. I believe they could be private if you put them in every activity or fragment that you need them in.

To be as clear as possible I would then call the methods to assign my view model in onCreate() in my activity and it would look something like this

```
private MyViewModel myViewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myViewModel = obtainViewModel(this, MyViewModel.class);
}
```

or in fragment

```
private MyViewModel myViewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        myViewModel = obtainFragmentViewModel(getActivity(), MyViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of [BeirDav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058343/624814) is

```
val vm = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```